# Incrustar reporte PDF de JaspertReport en JSP Aplicacion Web

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

He creado un reporte usando iReport de modo que, desde codigo java, y usando un HashMap, le paso los parametros al reporte.
Desde el servlet, si deseo visualizar en el navegador, lo hace sin problema e incluso permite la opcion de descargar.
El problema viene a la hora de intentar incrustar el PDF en un archivo jsp.

No se produce ningun tipo de error pero no se carga el pdf en la pagina jsp.

El codigo del servlet es el siguiente;

```
    package controllers;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;

/**
 *
 * @author Informatica
 */
@WebServlet(name = "ServletReporte", urlPatterns = {"/ServletReporte"})
public class ServletReporte extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){



    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"reporte.pdf\";");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");


            Conexion con = new Conexion();
            Connection conn = con.getConnection();

        try {
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();



            JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/reporte2.jasper"));




                    Map parametros = new HashMap<>();

            //parametros.put("codreserva", "codreserva");
            parametros.put("descripcion", "Pista de Padel 1");
            parametros.put("nombre", "Pista de Padel 1");
            parametros.put("dni", "00000000A");
            parametros.put("telefono", "66666666");
            parametros.put("precio", 5);
            parametros.put("doc_num", 45648);
            parametros.put("codigoreserva", "4568321");



                  JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros,conn);

      JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
      exporter.exportReport();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }










    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Y el codigo del jsp es el siguiente

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: blue">

            <object type="application/pdf" data="http://localhost:8080/ReporteWeb/ServletReporte" width="500" height="650"></object>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Pero no se muestra el PDF en la pagina JSP.

He seguido este pequeño ejemplo:

https://www.javatutoriales.com/2009/04/creacion-de-reportes-con-jasperrepots-y.html

Espero su ayuda porque, como ya les he comentado, el reporte se genera, y se descarga bien y con todos los parametros rellenos del HashMap. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Probaste con `Content-Disposition` `inline`?

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco tuve un problema parecido, lo arreglé sustituyendo el  de html por un  como por ejemplo así:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/ReporteWeb/ServletReporte" height="600px" width="100%">

</iframe>
```

Saludos.